# PHP framework work flow

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I am confused about how a php framework works with a web server like apache. Now if there wasn't a framework and if it was using classic php, then I understand how it works(if a php file is requested, the php parser executes it and returns the htm to the server).

When a framework like cakePHP is used, I have noticed that no matter which url the client requests, the `index.php` in the root folder gets executed first. How is this possible? if we were using pure php then, only the file we requested will get executed. So how does cakePHP make each and every request to go through the `/index.php` file?

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by that?

Comment: Check out [Introduction to URL Rewriting](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) for a fairly well written overview of the topic (which may answer a lot of your questions about it too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP, and many other websites, leverage [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which is an Apache module that "*Provides a rule-based rewriting engine to rewrite requested URLs on the fly*".

To do so, the web framework will use a `.htaccess` file with specific rules defined. These rules, in the case you're asking about, point any URL matching a specific pattern to to a *real* `index.php` file (this file can be named anything really, but `index.php` is a good "default" name).

Per CakePHP's [URL Rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) outline, a base rule is defined as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What the above does is:

1. Turns on the rewrite module
2. Sets two conditions for rewriting the current URL

   a. *Only* if the requested file is not a real directory (`!-d`)

   b. *Only* if the requested file is not a real file (`!-f`)
3. Sends the full requested URL, `(.*)` to `index.php`

Sometimes, you'll see the `RewriteRule` line as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will set the requested url into the `$_GET['url']` parameter instead of forcing the application to process the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Other times, there will be a lot of rewrite rules, some complicated, some basic.

There are a lot of good resources online, and in books, regarding `mod_rewrite`. Check out [Introduction to URL Rewriting](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) for one (it's one I have bookmarked, has a lot of good basic rules / formats).

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty simple one (https://github.com/gilbitron/PIP).
Read the files in the System folder.
Basically it goes like this:

All requests are sent to the index file (with mod_rewrite, or like a plain get parameter).

The index file includes configuration files and definitions of constants.

Then it loads the main class for the framerwork.

The main class does some configurations, initiates a database connection and so on.

Depending on how it is implemented, there might be a router but it's possible there isn't.If there is one the main class checks what controller should be loaded against the request in the router.

Then the main class loads the controller that should be loaded with that particular request.

PIP is not that good and the main class is actually not a class but you can get the point in it.

---

You can also read about the following things:

Object oriented programming: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Scopes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Autoloading classes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

> "I have noticed that no matter which url the client requests, the index.php in the root folder gets executed first."

This is what front controllers do. You can have a front controller with a framework or if coding from scratch using the .htaccess file. Front controllers enable rendering of pages using PHP functions/methods, such as `$app->get($uri, $callback);` in Lumen.